# accessing child class attributes from parent static methods in pydantic models

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pymongo, pydantic

Given a pydantic BaseModel class defined as follows:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from uuid import uuid4

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from server.database import get_db


class Campaign(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    name: str

    @staticmethod
    async def all() -> List:
        ret = get_db()['campaigns'].find()
        return [Campaign(**i) async for i in ret]

    @staticmethod
    async def get(id):
        ret = await get_db()['campaigns'].find_one({'id': id})
        return Campaign(**ret)

    async def save(self):
        await get_db()['campaigns'].insert_one(self.dict())

    async def update(self, **kwargs):
        await get_db()['campaigns'].update_one(
            {'id': self.id},
            {'$set': kwargs},
        )
```

As you can see from the above model defination that the functions [**all**, **get**, **save**, **update**] can be universal for multiple CRUD models like as follows:

```
class Record(BaseModel):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    async def all() -> List:
        ret = get_db()['records'].find()
        return [Record(**i) async for i in ret]

    async def save(self):
        pass

class Fragment(BaseModel):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    async def all() -> List:
        ret = get_db()['fragments'].find()
        return [Fragment(**i) async for i in ret]

    async def save(self):
        pass
```

Across all these methods of different classes the only change is the name of the MongoDB collection. Right now, I am copy pasting this code multiple times for different models.

Is there any generic solution so that I can encapsulate the definition of these methods under a single base class and hopefully follow the DRY principle (as opposed to blatantly breaking it right now).

One such code configuration can be:

```
class BaseDBModel(BaseModel):
    async def save(self):
        await get_db()[self.__class__.Meta.collection_name].insert_one(self.dict())

    async def update(self, **kwargs):
        await get_db()[self.__class__.Meta.collection_name].update_one(
            {'id': self.id},
            {'$set': kwargs},
        )

class Campaign(BaseDBModel):
    id: Optional[str] = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    name: str

    class Meta:
        collection_name = 'campaigns'
```

But, this code will only work for instance methods (i.e. **save**, **update**) and would not work for static methods like **all** and **get**. I am unsure as to how a parent class staticmethod will go about accessing the **Meta** class of the children in python?

Any suggestions or improvements on the above approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static methods should be class methods instead, so that the class *invoking* the method is passed as the first argument. For example,

```
class BaseDBModel(BaseModel):

    @classmethod
    async def all(cls) -> List:
        ret = get_db()[cls.Meta.collection_name].find()
        return [class(**i) async for i in ret]

    @classmethod
    async def get(id):
        ret = await get_db()[cls.Meta.collection_name]({'id': id})
        return class(**ret)

    async def save(self):
        await get_db()[self.Meta.collection_name].insert_one(self.dict())

    async def update(self, **kwargs):
        await get_db()[self.Meta.collection_name].update_one(
            {'id': self.id},
            {'$set': kwargs},
        )


class Campaign(BaseDBModel):
    id: Optional[str] = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    name: str
    
    class Meta:
        collection_name = 'campaigns'


class Record(Campaign):
    class Meta:
        collection_name = 'records'


class Fragment(Campaign):
    class Meta:
        collection_name = 'fragments'
```

(It's not clear if `Record` and `Fragment` should inherit from `Campaign` or `BaseDBModel` directly.)

Comment: yeah thanks a lot! that was what I was looking for. I completely forgot about the classmethods in python and was going about solving it in a convoluted way (like using metaclasses and class decorators lol..)

Comment: Just about any time you start thinking about metaclasses, that means you are probably overlooking a better solution :)